# MongoDB: Upsert document in array field

Tags: mongodb

Suppose, I have the following database:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    name: 'Alice',
    courses: [
        {
            _id: 'DB103',
            credits: 6
        },
        {
            _id: 'ML203',
            credits: 4
        }
    ]
},
{
    _id: 2,
    name: 'Bob',
    courses: []
}
```

I now want to 'upsert' the document with the course id 'DB103' in both documents. Although the `_id` field should remain the same, the `credits` field value should change (i.e. to 4). In the first document, the respective field should be changed, in the second one, `{_id: 'DB103', credits: 4}` should be inserted into the `courses` array.

Is there any possibility in MongoDB to handle both cases?

Sure, I could search with $elemMatch in courses for 'DB103' and if I haven't found it, insert, otherwise update the value. But these are two steps and I would like to do both in just one.